# Angular CLI build is adding @angular/material typings into vendor file

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular2-aot

[image: Bundle report for my project]

Angular CLI is including the @angular/material typings into the vendor file. I have no idea why it is doing this. I've looked over my source code searching for cause of this but i couldn't find it. What could be the reason for this and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Are you lazy loading your modules by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I'm loading all the modules except one